# Uploading file to Openshift server with servlet

Tags: java, file, servlets, upload, openshift

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before, but I could not find any resources on the internet answering my specific problem.

I am trying to upload a file from an Android app to my Openshift server/gear, where it will be stored. However, the issue I am facing is that whilst the file is being created at the Openshift side (I have checked using FTP), no data is being written to it.

The code snippet from the servlet that writes the data to the file is here:

```
int BUFFER_LENGTH = 4096;
DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(req.getInputStream());
String fileName = din.readUTF();
String path = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR") + "/uploads/" + fileName + ".txt";
File f = new File(path);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
int length = 0;
while ((length = din.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_LENGTH)) != -1) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

fos.close();
din.close();
```

It all seems to be correct, to me at least, and it worked when I tested it on a local tomcat server. For some reason, however, it doesn't work with Openshift, so there must be something I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily there is a help center article for just this issue:
https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-upload-and-serve-files-using-java-servlets-on-openshift

It details the code for both uploading, and serving files on OpenShift via a Java Servlet, using the openshift data directory

Comment: I have already looked at this resource and when first writing the servlet I basically copied the upload section but this did not work for me at all. It didn't even create the file at the server side. This may have something to do with the article being 2 years old, perhaps things have changed.